# How many mattresses are needed to cushion the fall?

Tags: kinematics

Have kinda a weird problem here that I can't figure out, I have a projectile in the top of its paraobola, at Vo = 0. When it hits the ground its Vf will be equal to 16.8559. It will take t= 1.216 seconds to fall to the ground.The height at v0 is 10 meters.

The idea is that the projectile is a person, and that they must hit the ground at 0 M/S to cushion their fall. Each mattress , and each mattress will absorb 1.0 is .2 meters thick and absorb 1 m/s of speed. The goal is to be at 0 upon landing.

The goal is to find the least amount of mattresses needed, however it is difficult, as I know the more mattresses their are, the greater the height and thus the less amount of speed. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: About 6.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjlBdNbLhBQ

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to solve this problem?

Treat the height as an unknown $h$ and write the equations of motion using that, so the distance travelled is $s=10 - h$, then calculate the final velocity using the usual constant-acceleration $v=u+at$, $s=ut+1/2at^2$ stuff. Since you have all the information about the acceleration and times, you're probably supposed to work out $a$ from that data, rather than assume $a=g=9.8 m /s^2$.